# Ordering a list of Functions using Big O

Tags: algorithm, analysis, big-o

I am currently working on some algorithms homework and I have a few questions I would like clarified so that I can make sure that the work I am doing is correct.

One of the questions asks us to compare ~20 functions by the big-Oh notation and then group together functions that are big-theta of one another. To order them, I graphed each one from 0 to 100 and compared the graphs to find which was better than the others. Is this a correct method of comparing? If there is an easier method, what can I do? How am I able to tell if one function is big-theta of another function? For example, a small part of the list that I have so far is this:

```
1/n

2^100

log(log(n))

n^.5 , 3n^.5
```

These two are grouped, yet I am not exactly sure how it is found that one is big-theta of the other.. it was my class mate that suggested it to me

```
2^(log(n)), 5n
```

Any and all help is appreciated.. I am struggling to wrap my head around Big O, Theta and the likes.

Comment: As a hint, can you simplify 2^(log n)?

Comment: 2^(log n) would just simplify to n so 2^(log n) is O(n) and 5n is O(n)... right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This notation has to do with time complexity theory and how problem size (ie. size of 'solution' space) is a function of the size of the input parameters.

Your question is more of a mathematics question and would be more suited for the Mathematics Exchange. Having said that, [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) is a good starting point for you.

Generally problems are divided into (from simplest to most complex):

- Constant time solvable - O(1)
- Log time solvable - O(log(n))
- Polynomial time solvable - O(n^2)
- Super-polynomial time solvable (more than polynomial)
- Exponential time solvable - O(2^poly(n))

If you'd like to determine how they are ranked, pick a set N = {1...n} and plug each element of this set into each function and plot how quickly they individually increase in size.